# Best way to query a model with search and pass its id into another model

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Can I get some help? I am trying to query my model database as a search. When the results are fetched, I want to pass the id of the collection through a form into another model and I don't want to use a package.

So, far, I have been getting errors.

Basically, I am querying the database with

```
$services = Service::where('name' 'LIKE' Request::('input')):
```

But if I try to pass to pass $servces to view with

```
return view('search.result')->with($services);
```

It returns **Illegal Offset Type. **

So, instead I have to chain the $services in details
Like so:

```
return view('search.results')->withDetails($services);
```

On my results.blade.php, I have:

```
@foreach($details as $d) 
{{$d->name}} 
<form action="{{route('book', ['id' =>$d->id} method="POST">
<button type="submit">Book</button>
</form>
@endforeach
```

This displays the services collections

But, if I try to pass to pass the Id of $d collection into the Book model like this:

```
public function book($id) {
$service = Service::find($id);

//or

$service = Service::where('id', $id) ;

App\Models\Book::insert([
'service_I'd => $service->id]) ;
```

It tells me that id does not exist on this
Collection instance.

Can someone help me with a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

in your line:

> $services = Service::where('name' 'LIKE' Request::('input')):

it should be:

```
$services = Service::where('name', 'LIKE', Request::('input'))->get();
```

or if you want to get similar names:

```
$services = Service::where('name', 'LIKE','%'. Request::('input').'%')->get();
```

and in this line:

> ```
> $service = Service::where('id', $id) ;
> ```

you can use:

```
$service = Service::firstWhere('id', $id) ;
```

Comment: It returned trying to get property of non object model

Comment: Its the ``` $service = Service::findWhere('id',  $id) ; ```

Comment: findWhere is ok, but why not firstWhere too?

Answer (score 0):

So, to pass the id of the returned collection to the new model, I had to use

```
///Then, 

Book::insert([
'service_Id => $service->id]);
```

Thanks a lot everyone.